# Add an elapsed time format to a datetime in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

Given the value `4/1/2013 20:07:11` and a column called Elapsed Time which has values such as `00:00:00:00:000` which is `00:hh:mm:ss:fff`, I'd like to derive a column which is the date value + the elapsed time.

For example:

```
AcquisitionDate:     4/1/2013 20:07:11
Date                      Elapsed
4/1/2013 20:07:11:000     00:00:00:00:000
4/1/2013 20:07:12:984     00:00:00:01:984
4/1/2013 20:07:14:984     00:00:00:03:984
```

Is this possible?

**Edit** - Some additional information

This all comes from a CSV file, the raw data looks exactly like this:

```
Acquisition Date:   4/1/2013 8:07:11 PM
Scan Elapsed           101 <Left> (C)  102 <Center> (C)  103 <Right> (C)
1    00:00:00:00:000   23.327          23.207            23.105
2    00:00:00:01:984   23.386          23.292            23.174
...
638  00:00:21:13:984   213.58          217.361           211.845
```

I ultimately am trying to write some script (or Macro... whatever it takes in Excel land) which will perform some action on >1000 CSV files in a directory.  The process was simply open the CSV in excel and now I'm dealing with whatever formatting it gives me.

The Elapsed column right now is "General" and there is no Date formatting that fits this style.

Comment: Doesn't adding and formatting as appropriate produce the required result?

Comment: I'm not able to add the two together (because it produces an error)

Comment: What do you get when you add the two together? (there are different types of errors: `#N/A`, `#VALUE!`, etc) Note that I don't have MS Excel 2010, but the format of your elapsed time is suspicious. Is the elapsed time perhaps stored as text?

Comment: It produces `#VALUE!` and I've added some further details to the original post

Comment: Hmm, a macro would indeed be ideal for that many files (I'm not that good in them). Otherwise, I guess a formula can be made.

Comment: I'm not familiar with macro's either, but I'd imagine either way I need to be able to do it once (via some formula) and then have the macro replicate that behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the date plus the time, you can use this:

```
=$B$1+SUBSTITUTE(MID(B3,4,LEN(B3)),":",".",3)
```

`B1` is where the acquisition date is and `B3` is where the first elapsed time is.

Format the result as `dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss.000` using custom format.

Then drag down to the bottom.

One thing though, I'm ignoring the leading `00:` in the elapsed time (and I don't know that it might be, days perhaps if it's relevant?). If there is a value there, it won't be considered in the formula!

Comment: Awesome!  Worked perfectly.

Comment: @Tom Okay, if you discover what this leading `00:` is and that this is causing some trouble, let me know and I'll whack up something to consider it :)